# How to target one checkbox and based on its value show input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function selectOpenField() {
    $("input[name='vrije_velden']").on('click', function() {

            var $box = $(this);
            if ($box.is(":checked")) {

                var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
                $(group).prop("checked", false);
                $box.prop("checked", true);

                var val = $(this).val();

                $("input[name='vrije_velden']").each(function(key, value){
                    var $thisValue = $(value).val();
                    if ($thisValue === val) {
                        $('#'+val).slideDown();
                    } else {
                        $(group).slideUp();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $box.prop("checked", false);
                $(group).slideUp();
            }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox" 
    value="checkboxHolder" name="vrije_velden">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
 </div>
 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="radio" 
    value="radioBoxHolder" name="vrije_velden">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="radio">Radio</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="input" 
    value="inputBoxHolder" name="vrije_velden">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="input">Input</label>
</div>
```

I have created 3 checkboxes, however there can only be one checkbox checked and not multiple. All good.

***My problem***

I am showing certain divs based on the value of the checkbox which has been checked, this works, but when I click on another checkbox, to show div B, div A does not dissapear. The second problem is, that when I click on on a checkbox and uncheck this one again, the div also remains.

***This part is the most recent piece of code I tried***

```
var val = $(this).val();
                $("input[name='vrije_velden']").each(function(key, value){
                    var $thisValue = $(value).val();
                    if ($thisValue === val) {
                        $('#'+val).slideDown();
                    } else {
                        $(group).slideUp();
                    }
                });
```

***What I wish to achieve***

- 3 checkboxes, only one can be checked (radio button type), but user should also be able to uncheck (that's the reason I am not using radio buttons)
- When I click on checkbox A, div A should show, when I click on checkbox B, checkbox A becomes unchecked and div A goes back to `display: none`, but div B shows (and so on) the value of the checkboxes are also the IDs of the divs.
- When I click on checkbox A, div A should show, but when I uncheck checkbox A, div A should be `display: none` again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question: where would those divs would be? Next to these checkboxes, or under them or far away from them? Depending on it there can be multiple solutions

Comment: They are underneath all the checkboxes. So underneath all the HTML code you see in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, this should do it:

In this code, if you check a checkbox, the div under it will appear,and any other divs disappear, and if you uncheck it, it disappears.

So basically only one div can be seen.

```js
$(function(){
$("input[name='vrije_velden']").on("click",function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")){
$("input[name='vrije_velden']").not($(this)).prop("checked",false);
var val=$(this).attr("value");
$(".div").each(function(){
if($(this).attr("id")==val){
$(this).removeClass("none");
}
else{
$(this).addClass("none");
}
});
}
else{
$(".div").addClass("none");
}
});
});
```

```css
.none{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox" 
    value="checkboxHolder" name="vrije_velden">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>

 </div>
 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="radio" 
    value="radioBoxHolder" name="vrije_velden">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="radio">Radio</label>
 
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="input" 
    value="inputBoxHolder" name="vrije_velden">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="input">Input</label>

</div>


    <div class="div none" id="checkboxHolder">
Checkbox div
</div>
<br>
   <div class="div none" id="radioBoxHolder">
Radio div
</div>
<br>
    <div class="div none" id="inputBoxHolder">
Input div
</div>
```

Comment: May I ask why you opted to go for the class custom-control-input as selector? Although your code works etc. and it is NOT wrong, my 3 divs are all underneath the checkboxes. so it's: 'checkbox' - 'checkbox' - 'checkbox' and then the DIVs.

Comment: I updated my answers, I've missed some details in your question, let me know if it's better now.